# How to move XML element and add a child element at the same time with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

What I'm trying to accomplish here is move an element (including it child nodes), and then add a child node within that element, or vice versa.  It seems that I can only do one thing at a time.  Is possible to do both at the same time?

Here is my input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <box1>
        <cd1>
            <title>Title 1</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd1>
        <cd2>
            <title>Title 2</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
            <year>1988</year>
        </cd2>
    </box1>
    <box2>
        <cd3>
            <title>Title 3</title>
            <artist>Metallica</artist>
        </cd3>
    </box2>
</catalog>
```

Would like to have the output like this

```
<catalog>
<box1>
    <cd1>
        <title>Title 1</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd1>
    <cd2>
        <title>Title 2</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd2>
    <cd3>
        <title>Title 3</title>
        <artist>Metallica</artist>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd3>
</box1>
```

As you can see element cd3 moved and a child node of  is added as well.

Here is what I did and all it does just moving the element regardless what order I put of the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- add a child element -->
    <xsl:template match="cd3">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <year>1990</year>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- move node -->
    <xsl:template match="/catalog">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
                <xsl:copy-of select="box2/cd3"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="box2"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<xsl:copy-of select="box2/cd3"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="box2/cd3"/>` and change `<xsl:template match="/catalog">` to `<xsl:template match="/catalog/box1">`.

Comment: Martin, I did as you suggested and the element <cd3> is not displaying.

Comment: @user1998820, yes, it seems with your original stylesheet it was a bit difficult to only suggest some edits, the suggestion to use `apply-templates` is correct, furthermore the change to `<xsl:template match="/catalog/box1">` also simplifies the approach but I overlooked that then you also need to adapt the path of the apply-templates to `<xsl:apply-templates select="../box2/cd3"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by following code below.  Thanks for the help got me started on further investigation.

```
<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:copy>
        <box1>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="box2/cd3"/>
        </box1>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```